# Swift extension - Parse Json to NSDictionary Model (By Using Category Like In Obj-C)

Tags: objective-c, swift, nsdictionary, extension-methods, categories

I have API request to get json string, something like that:

```
{  
  "data":[  
    {  
     "id":123,
     "name":"Felix"},
    {  
     "id":122,
     "name":"Mary"},
    {  
     "id":111,
     "name":"Jason"},
   ]
}
```

and in my Obj-C NSDictionary+user is

```
-(NSString *)usrId
{
    return self[@"id"];
}

-(NSString *)usrName
{
    return self[@"name"];
}
...
```

and when I use this I import the category class, and access it like dict.name...

I can't find a good answer related to this question. How can I achieve this in Swift?

---

**UPDATED [2017.07.21]**

I've chose to use **SwiftyJSON** library to settle all the json-dictionary-object-mapping works. Save tons of time.

[SwiftyJSON](https://cocoapods.org/pods/SwiftyJSON)

Comment: Why don't we make a model class rather than using Dictionary category?
We can parse in the init of model class and later on we can fetch

Answer (score 0):

Best and safest way to parse json response to nsdictionary and use it in swift is:

```
var responseRecord<datastruct> = Array<datastruct>()             

struct datastruct
{
    var id: String?
    var name:String?

    init(add: NSDictionary)
    {
        id = add["id"] as? String
        name = add["name"] as? String
    }
}
```

And to access it in program:

`print(self.responseRecord.id)
 print(self.responseRecord.name)`

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a empty Swift class with required properties **(Swift 2.2)**:-

```
class myClass {

var id:Int?
var name:String?

 init(id:Int,name:String)
 {
 self.id= id
 self.name = name
 }
}
```

Then to access in required VC :-

```
    var requiredData:[String]?
    var data:[myClass]?

    override fun viewDidLoad()
    {
    super.viewDidLoad()
     requiredData = data!.enumerate().map({ (index, category) in
                return ("\(category.name!)")
                })

print(requiredData)


    }
```

Note: I am assuming you have already populated data in the mentioned "data" variable of myClass type. If not, then you can do so as follows:-

```
data = [myClass(id:1,name:"aaa"),myClass(id:2,name:"bob"),myClass(id:3,name:"ccc")]
```